# Computing Moving Average and Updating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been struggling to add a moving average to a dataset.  Here's what I have to work with:

```
ID, SamplerName,  CreatedOn,  Average, MovingAverage
1,    type A,    05/01/2016,     100,       null
2,    type B,    05/01/2016,     110,       null
3,    type A,    05/02/2016,     105,       null
4,    type B,    05/02/2016,     102,       null
```

This is a very simplified example of my data, in reality I have about 15 SamplerNames and it's possible to change in the future.

I tried setting up a cursor to loop through a list generated by doing a select distinct on the sampler label in the table then updating the MovingAverage by doing something similar to 
`AVG([Average]) OVER (ORDER BY [CreatedOn] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)` but I ran into the error

> "window functions can only appear in select or order by clauses".

I've tried a number of other solutions but I can't quite figure it out and I was hoping someone could give me a hand.

Comment: you can often calculate moving averages using JOIN to previous records, then utilising AVG on the prior records selected, but I'm not sure exactly what your definition of moving average is here.

Comment: @JaydipJ  I'm not sure I understand your comment.  The moving average I'm looking to calculate is the moving average of all previous SamplerNames so for instance, the first instance of TypeA created  on 5/1/2016 should have a moving average of 100 and TypeA created on 5/2/2016 should be (100 +105)/2.  TypeB would be similar and the calculations limited to the typeB SamplerNames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows / range clause was introduced in [SQL Server 2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). If you are using 2008+, you are missing the `partition by SamplerName`

```
avg(Average) over (partition by SamplerName order by CreatedOn rows unbounded preceding)
```

Example:

```
declare @T table (ID int, SamplerName varchar(6), CreatedOn datetime, Average float)

insert into @T (ID, SamplerName, CreatedOn, Average)
select 1, 'type A', '2016-05-01', 100 union all
select 2, 'type B', '2016-05-01', 110 union all
select 3, 'type A', '2016-05-02', 105 union all
select 4, 'type B', '2016-05-02', 102


select *,
    avg(Average) over (partition by SamplerName order by CreatedOn rows unbounded preceding)
from @T
```

Comment: You're correct, I was missing the partition by in my over clause.  I was able to just move that average calculation into the stored proc that moves data into my reporting database and get the calculation without the need of an update afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate  as (
      select t.*,
             avg(average) over (partition by sampler order by createdon) as new_movingaverage
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set movingaverage = new_movingaverage;
```

Comment: getting "Invalid column name 'new_movingAverage'."

Comment: @Austin . .  . That error doesn't make sense.  The column is defined in the CTE.